# Is ARIMA appropriate for time series prediction involving a mix of explanatory and independent variables?

Tags: machine-learning, python, r, prediction

I have a table with the following columns:

Date(Month,Year), Sold_Past_Month, Quantity_Available, Quantity_Shipping_In, Missed_Sales, Quantity_Needed

Quantity_Needed is the dependent variable that is numerical.

I want to predict Quantity_Needed and train a model using the columns mentioned above; however, I also want Quantity_Needed to train the model.

I have data from the past 5 years -> so I would have roughly 60 rows of data for one item.

Is it possible to use ARIMA for this?

If it is, what should I do next to build my model?

Comment: Hey! Welcome! Yes, ARIMA is actually constructed with time series in mind. If you are going to be successful is something you will only know if you try. You can go trough [this tutorial](https://www.ethanrosenthal.com/2018/03/22/time-series-for-scikit-learn-people-part2/) for creating an ARIMA model with sklearn in Python.

Answer (score 1):

The correct name of what you are looking for is: [ARIMAX](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/), the ARIMA model works without covariables, the X (exogenous variables) include the possibility of having other explanatory variables.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the nature of this problem because I see that even the independent variables are linked to their past values, if so and if you don’t have a test data set you can try VAR model.

> In a VAR model, each variable is a linear function of the past values
>   of itself and the past values of all the other variables.

Otherwise you can also use LSTMs.